# Multiply two lists component-wise in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, multiplication

I would like to create a function in Prolog that multiplies two lists together component-wise and returns the resulting list.

For example:

```
?- multiply_lists([1,2,3], [4,5,6], X).
X = [4,10,18].
```

I would like to write this function without using built-in Prolog functions.

Answer (score 1):

First define the base case - the result of multiplying two empty lists together is the empty list.

```
multl([],[],[]).
```

Then, define the recursive part of the function:

```
multl([H1|Tail1],[H2|Tail2], [H3|Tail3]):-
        multl(Tail1, Tail2, Tail3),
        H3 is (H1 * H2).
```

What's happening here is that the elements at the head of both lists are being multiplied together and being concatenated with the tail of the result.

All in all, we have:

```
multl([],[],[]).
multl([H1|Tail1],[H2|Tail2], [H3|Tail3]):-
    multl(Tail1, Tail2, Tail3),
    H3 is (H1 * H2).
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting is

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

mutiply(X,Y,Z) :-
    Z #= X*Y.

multiply_lists(L1, L2, Out) :-
    maplist(mutiply, L1,L2,Out).
```

With results :

```
?-  multiply_lists([1,2,3], [4,5,6], X).
X = [4, 10, 18].

?- multiply_lists(X, [4,5,6], [4,8,10]).
false.

?- multiply_lists(X, [4,5,6], [4,10,18]).
X = [1, 2, 3].

?- multiply_lists(X, Y, [4,10,18]).
X = [_17366, _17372, _17378],
Y = [_17396, _17402, _17408],
_17366 in -4.. -1\/1..4,
_17366*_17396#=4,
_17396 in -4.. -1\/1..4,
_17372 in -10.. -1\/1..10,
_17372*_17402#=10,
_17402 in -10.. -1\/1..10,
_17378 in -18.. -1\/1..18,
_17378*_17408#=18,
_17408 in -18.. -1\/1..18.
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I needed to write the function from scratch, without using any library functions.